# uncertainty in dependent variable at single covariate

Tags: regression, distributions, predictive-models, linear-model, prediction

I have a dataset consisting of responses of a dependent variable measured at the same independent variables over multiple trials. It looks something like trial $i$: $(x^{(i)}_1, y^{(i)}_1) = (1.0,\tilde{y}^{(i)}_1),\, (x^{(i)}_2, y^{(i)}_2) = (1.5,\tilde{y}^{(i)}_2),\, \ldots, (x^{(i)}_n, \tilde{y}^{(i)}_n) = (10.0,\tilde{y}^{(i)}_n)$ where the tildes indicate an observed response.

Can I incorporate the different variances at each covariate into the prediction interval?

Is there a standard approach to fit the distribution of the $\{\tilde{y}^{(i)}_j\}_{i=1}^n$? If I were to use linear regression, would the confidence and prediction intervals change from the standard case?